# Size subpanel needed for mini house

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel

I have 400 amp service in a 3800 square-foot home. I ran 100 amp to a garage.  I want to build a mini-home that will require approximately 130amps in appliances, etc. What size sub-panel do I need?

The mini house will  have:

- stove 40 amp
- water heater 18.75 amp
- stackable washer dryer 30 amp
- heat pump 8.87 amp
- dishwasher 20 amp
- fridge 8.5 amp
- microwave/hood 15 amp
- lights & outlets

That's why I figured 130 amps. The load in the main house should be able to handle a 100 to 150 amp sub panel. Need help deciding what size I should use.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack exchange!  Approx 130 what?  It looks a bit like your question may have posted while you were still in the middle of writing it -- if that's the case you can use the edit button to add the rest of the info to your question.

Comment: amps in appliances etc that will be in mini house

Comment: We are all glad To hear of your project , but if your question is do you have enough power available to power a tiny house with 130 amps, I would ask a bunch of questions including how in the world are you going to put enough equipment in a tiny house to need a massive panel like that. Most motor homes max out at 50 amps and many only need 30 amps 120v.  To provide any kind of answer we would need to know the loads on your existing house and garage including heat, cooking type of water heater &  dryer , you may be able to provide another sub panel but if your home is 100% base board heat ?

Comment: To follow up on Ed's comment: 130A sounds like a LOT but keep in mind that, for example, 3 20A circuits for receptacles would not actually "use up" 60A in a panel (there are various calculations) plus a panel has "double" because it is 240V and most (but not all) circuits are 120V - e.g., 2 120V 20A circuits use only 20A @ 240V. So a **lot** more detail would help.

Comment: The process the code defines for a residential load calculation is based on square footage, specific appliances, and expected load diversity. There are forms that use some technical descriptions that are sometimes defined uniquely by the NEC. There are also some calculators that you might find useful.  https://ask-the-electrician.com/residential-electrical-load-calculation.html

Comment: @EdBeal I can name that tune in 1 appliance: on-demand water heater.

Comment: mini house has dishwasher 20 amp,fridge 8.5 amp, stove 40 amp micro hood 15 amp, water heater 18.75 amp, stackable washer dryer 30 amp heat pump 8.87 amp lights & outlets; that's why i figured 130 amps.  The load in the main house should be able to handle a 100 to 150 amp sub panel. Need help deciding what size i should use.

Comment: Now I know you have only added every load possible as the others that have a ‘clue or think they have one ‘ have never wired a tiny house ,,,OOPS YES I HAVE AND FOR FREE, to help , I no longer do this after so many don’t have a clue , power comes from some place at 130 amp for a tiny house , are they kidding , Rotflmao, tiny houses should be much more efficient , my much larger farm house draws less than 80 amps and we are all electric.

Comment: How many square feet is this tiny house?  That's what determines your lighting/outlet loads then and there...

Comment: @EdBeal Well, if it is a tiny house with lots of not-so-tiny servers mining Bitcoin...

Comment: @manassehkatz those are called "electric resistive heaters"...

Comment: The idea of a tiny house is a tiny impact on the environment, the tinys I have helped with had an average of 35 or 40 amps and most of this was was for the composting toilet! Heat was less than 3kw if I remember correctly and this included hot water. A Bitcoin is not part of my states power calculation, call it whatever you want but tiny houses / less than 500 sf , give me a break , yes I have only wired a few and this I did for free to help the homeless, never seen a tiny house that needs this kind of power,,  provide an answer if you want a lot of down votes from the Pacific Northwest

Comment: This sounds to me **not** like a true "tiny house" but rather more like a "small house next to a big house (3800 sqft!)" - i.e., "mini" is relative and not in the "tiny" sense.

Comment: NEVER MIND!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Tina Gregory don't get discouraged by the "sparkies" hashing it out, hang in there for a helpful answer (or reference the calculators mentioned in one of the comments...) If a comment asks for more info., try to provide it by editing it into your question, that helps with quality answers.

Comment: @TinaGregory -- we *really* need a square footage for this house

Comment: @EdBeal -- the OP is really building a detached ADU, not a "tiny house" in the sense you're thinking of

Comment: @TinaGregory -- also, where are you on this planet? Heat pump emergency heat is second only to instantaneous electric hot water heaters at murdering service calculations...

Answer (score 2):

I ran your loads through a calculator and it spit out a main panel load of 66 amps.  That tells me you are probably alright.  But I am concerned you are not talking about heat pump emergency heat.  Heat pumps do not work in very cold temperatures, that's where emergency heat comes in. *I note this building doesn't have any gas*.

So while I think it'll work at 100A, I'd feel more comfortable seeing 150A because I worry that there are things you've left out.   So that's where I am with feeder.

As far as your subpanel size, there are 2 things we're concerned with.

### Number of spaces in the panel

The usual mistake is to consider only panel ampacity and get a panel that is much too small (in spaces).  Remember, you have an all-electric house, which means a lot of 240V (2-pole, double-sized) breakers. You need the same number of electric appliances as a bigger house, they just have smaller numbers on the breaker.  So even a 30-space panel would be scary-small.  I would aim for 40-space.

There's a scam out there called "Circuits" - such as a panel that is 20-space/40-circuit. That relies on breakers that are now illegal - panel makers shouldn't be making these claims anymore, but they are.  By "Illegal" I mean a 40-"circuit" panel relies on very few of them being AFCI/GFCI or common-trip -- and in fact, most of them must be!

### Ampacity of the panel

The amp rating of the subpanel *itself* is flexible.  **It only needs to be greater or equal to the supply breaker**. So if your supply breaker is 100A, then you can use a 100A, 125, 150, 200 or 225A subpanel.

Because it is an outbuilding not connected by a breezeway, your house will need its own main disconnect switch.  The easiest/cheapest way to get that is select a panel *with* a main breaker.  Again, any size will do >= the feed breaker size.

If you think "I'll get them the same size so the nearby breaker will trip first", unfortunately it does not work that way. It's a coin-flip  which one will trip first, unless it is raining and you are dressed for bed, then it will be the far one obviously.